# mongoose ref sub field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I want to populate myBook.title by refing to sub field/id of subject.book._id 
Is it possible?

```
let subject= new Schema({
     subjectTitle{
         first:String,
         last: String,
     },
     book[
         {
             title: {type: String, required: true,unique:true}
         }
     ],
})

let myBook= new Schema({
     title: {type: ObjectId, ref:'subject.book'}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some small mistakes in your code:

```
const Subject = new Schema({
   subjectTitle: {
      first:String,
      last: String
   },
   book: [
      {
         title: {type: String, required: true, unique:true}
      }
   ],
});

const MyBook = new Schema({
   title: {type: ObjectId, ref:'Subject.book'}
});
```

However, I'm very unsure about `Subject.book` thing to work here, as I've never tried referencing part of a document. Please make sure it is correct way to reference a document's sub-part. Otherwise, I'll suggest you to split the document into two different document and reference it in the Subject's schema.

Also, if the object in your book field in Subject schema is going to contain only one field, its better to remove it for sake of simplicity, and make it like:

```
book: [
   {type: String, required: true, unique:true}
]
```

And now the answer to your question. When fetching documents from `MyBook`, you can populate the title field as:

```
MyBook.find({/*criteria here*/}).populate('title').exec((error, mybooks) => {
   if (error) //handle error
   console.log(mybooks[0].title);
});
```

Note that i've used `mybooks[0]`, as because `find()` method return an array of documents, even if your criteria will return a single document, it will be wrapped inside an array.

Also the output for the above `console.log()` statement will be an array of objects with title field and its string value. Or simple an array of string, if you simplify it as I've suggested you.

**Edit:** Re-structuring models design

As far as i've studied, the sub-parts of a document cannot be referred as you are trying to do so.
So instead, you can breakdown your models design as follows to achieve what you're trying to do.

```
const BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique:true
    }
    // any other book property goes here.
});

const SubjectSchema = new Schema({
    subjectTitle: {
       first:String,
       last: String 
    },
    book: [
        {
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: 'Book'
        }
    ]
});
```

so now you have a book collection with details of each books, and subject collection, where each subject can have many books as you want to have alongwith other properties.

to fetch a subject with all its book:

```
Subject.find({/*criteria here*/}).populate('book').exec((error, subjects) => {
    if (error) //handle error
    console.log(subjects[0].title);
});
```

and to find a book:

```
Book.find({/*criteria goes here*/}).exec((error, book) => {});
```

Comment: Hi @Himanshu Mittal
I am new to populate.

1. For title: `{type: ObjectId, ref:'Subject.book'}` i just put like that because i do not want to ref to Subject model but it's sup field which is book. I knew it's not correct, but just for showing what i want. Thanks

Comment: So it means it is not possible to ref to sub field of a model?

Comment: @sophanith please review the edit, and let me know if it answers your question. Also i apologize for late reply.